# DynamoDB enchanced client batch error response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the past while using DynamoDBMapper I was able to get information after batch put items about the error message. Right now doing the batch using EnchancedDynamoDBClient I can only get key of that item. Any way to get information why the batch for specific item didint work?

```
private void saveToDb(DynamoDbTable<PartImportWarehouse>partStockDataTable, List<PartImportWarehouse> modifiedImportaWrehouse, DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient) {
        WriteBatch.Builder<PartImportWarehouse> writeBatchBuilder = WriteBatch.builder(PartImportWarehouse.class)
                .mappedTableResource(partStockDataTable);

        modifiedImportaWrehouse.forEach(writeBatchBuilder::addPutItem);

        BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest batchRequestBuilder = BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .addWriteBatch(writeBatchBuilder.build())
                .build();

        BatchWriteResult batchWriteResult = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.batchWriteItem(batchRequestBuilder);

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(batchWriteResult.unprocessedPutItemsForTable(partStockDataTable))) {
            log.warn(batchWriteResult.unprocessedPutItemsForTable(partStockDataTable).stream()
                    .map(i -> "issue with " + i.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
    }
```

@Edit
In past I was able to get partial response for failed part with code like:
[image]
Dont mind the errors. I havent reloaded the project. But I was able to get errors for each part.